# Combo box data bound to listbox wont show display member

Tags: c#, .net, sql, wpf

I have a combo box that populates data from the database, which, based on a list box selection populates the data within a given list box through an SQL query. Problem is that the display member property wont show. I wont show the back-end sql because that works fine and the list box actually populates just not the display member. So the data in the list box is blank.

Here is the code:

The Combobox method:

```
private void populateFromMedication()
{
    MedicationList medicationItem = new MedicationList();

    // if item is selected
    if( !( ( Locations )cmbLocationDescriptionList.SelectedItem == null ) )
    {
        // set location to be the seletect location from the combo
        location = ( Locations )cmbLocationDescriptionList.SelectedItem;

        List<MedicationList> fromMedicatitionList = new List<MedicationList>();
        // retrieve a list of medication from the database
        fromMedicatitionList = LocationData.RetrieveMedicationByLocation( location.LocationID, GlobalVariables.SelectedResident.ResidentID );
        //bind the list for to the medication list
        lstMedicationForCurrentLocation.ItemsSource = fromMedicatitionList;

        lstMedicationForCurrentLocation.DisplayMemberPath = "Description";        
    } 
}
```

On form Initialization:

```
public FormInitialize()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadData();
    LoadResidentData();
    populateFromMedication();
}
```

MedicationList Class:

```
           public class MedicationList
{

    public int MedicationID { get; set; }



    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return Description;
        }
        set
        {
            Description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged( "Description" );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that

1) There is a property in `MedicationList` by the name `Description` and that `OnPropertyChanged` is applied on its setter.

```
string _Description;
public string Description
{
    get
    {
        return _Description;
    }
    set
    {
        _Description = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Description");
    }
}
```

For more on OnPropertyChanged read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)

2) Try giving `Displaymember` before providing `Itemsource`.

Comment: @Mark: In your class MedicationList is there a property by the name `Description`?

Comment: How do I go about changing the onPropertyChanged?

Comment: On property change doesnt exist in this context?